# Combinate JQuery Mobile component with spring

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jquery-mobile, spring-mvc

Currently, I use JQuery Mobile to create a web-mobile application. I've created a form with different fiels in this file :

```
<body>
    ...
    <div data-role="page" data-ajax="false" id="page1">
         <jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>

         <div data-role="content">

            <form id="myForm" method ="post" action="/Address" data-ajax="false">
                 <input name="streetName" id="streetName" placeholder="<spring:message code="streetName" />" value="" type="text">
                 <input name="streetNumber" id="streetNumber" placeholder="<spring:message code="streetNumber" />" value="" type="text">
                 <input name="zipCode" id="zipCode" placeholder="<spring:message code="zipCode" />" value="" type="text">
                 <input name="city" id="city" placeHolder="<spring:message code="city" />" value="" type="text">
                 <select name="select-country" id="country">

                      <option selected="selected" value="select a country">
                            <spring:message code="selectCountry" />
                      </option>

                      <% 
                       String[] locales = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getISOCountries();
                       List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
                       for(String countryCode : locales){
                            Locale loc = new Locale("",countryCode);
                            countryList.add(loc.getDisplayCountry());
                        }
                        Collections.sort(countryList);

                       for(String country : countryList){ 
                      %>

                      <option value=<%= country %>>
                          <%= country %>
                      </option>
                     <% } %>
                </select>

               <a id="validationBtn" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog" data-ajax="false"><spring:message code="adressValidateBtn" /></a>
         </form>
   </div>
 </div>

<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
          <h1><spring:message code="errorDetailsDialog" /></h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="text">
    </div>

 </div>
</body>
```

And my controller to check up the data from the form :

```
@Controller
public class AddressController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/address",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView init(){
         return new ModelAndView("address");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/address/{streetName}/{streetNumber}/{zipCode}/{city}/{country}")
    public ModelAndView validate(
         @RequestParam(value="streetName",required = true) String streetName,
         @RequestParam(value="streetNumber",required=true) String streetNumber,
         @RequestParam(value="zipCode",required = true) String zipCode,
         @RequestParam(value="city",required = true) String city,
         @RequestParam(value="country",required = true) String country
     ){
          //Control, check-up datas
     }}
```

When I read about the spring, I saw that it existed some Spring components as , , and that so it was possible that every fields represents a field of my data model(for example address.streetName, address.streetNumber,...) but I don't may use the spring components because I create a web-mobile application for smartphone.

Moreover, If it exists any errors while the data check-up, I would like to redirect the user to my dialog box(see above in the first example) by using the 'Errors' object and the  tag.

I would like to continue using spring framework with jquery mobile. What's the best choice ? What's your solution ?

Thank you